# Talend - Check tEsbConsumer Soap response and count fields with the same name

Tags: xml, soap, talend

I am trying to check if the response from tEsbConsumer activity contains more than one tag with specific name. Lets assume that the response looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:CustomerSearchResponse xmlns="http://test.com/CustomerSearchResponse/" xmlns:ns1="http://test.com/CustomerSearchResponse/">
         <ns1:Success>
            <ns1:Customers>
               <ns1:Customer>
                  <ns1:CustomerId>12</ns1:CustomerId>
                  <ns1:Surname>Sur1</ns1:Surname>
               </ns1:Customer>
               <ns1:Customer>
                  <ns1:CustomerId>34</ns1:CustomerId>
                  <ns1:Surname>Sur2</ns1:Surname>
               </ns1:Customer>
            </ns1:Customers>
         </ns1:Success>
      </ns1:CustomerSearchResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The code in TalendESB looks like this:

[image: Talend Code]

Based on the number of returned customers I would like to redirect message to different rows. Additional variable with count() variable will be ok for me as well. The xpaths in txmlmap are not working, tXSLT transformer needs to have a file on input and the tExtractXMLField is not working in such form:

[image: tExtractXMLField mapping]

Does anybody have idea how to do that?

Comment: You can use DOM Parser to calculate number on tags. you can do it in tJavaRow and based upon number you can pass the context ahead.

Comment: @Vish
If I would like to use tJavaRow, how should I parse the document type from input row?

Something like this is not working:

`InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(input_row.payload));
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
String tt = doc.getElementsByTagName("itemIdentifier").item(0).getTextContent();

System.out.println("Root element :" + tt);`